# converting txt file to list unquoted using python

Tags: python

i want to have this form

```
[(1, 'A'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'e'), (1, 'l'), (1, ' '), (1, 'a'), (1, 'n'), (1, 'd'), (1, ' '), (1, 'm'), (1, 'o'), (1, 'h'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'm'), (1, 'e'), (1, 'd')]
```

but i got this

```
["(1, 'A')", "(1, 'd')", "(1, 'e')", "(1, 'l')", "(1, ' ')", "(1, 'a')", "(1, 'n')", "(1, 'd')", "(1, ' ')", "(1, 'm')", "(1, 'o')", "(1, 'h')", "(1, 'a')", "(2, 'm')", "(1, 'e')", "(1, 'd')"]
```

and here is my code

```
def openRLEFile():
    file = askopenfile(parent=root,title='Select a File')
    global filename
    filename = file.name
    content = [x.strip('\n') for x in file]
    tDecompressed = decodeRLE(content)
    text.delete(0.0,END)
    text.insert(0.0,tDecompressed)
    file.close()
```

Comment: may be you should process your (sub) strings to transform them as you wish i.e. as tuples of int and character... What have you tried to do so?

Comment: @JulienBernu i'm stuck here buddy and have no idea what to do to have that form of list

Comment: did you create this file? maybe you should do it in different way.

Comment: Try this on bash terminal if you are on linux: `sed -i 's/"//g' filename`. It will replace all the `"` with empty space in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `eval()` as proposed by 宏杰李 works conveniently, it is often not recommended to use it for security purpose.

Instead you could process manually:

```
def my_process(x):
    x = x[1:-1] # get rid of brackets
    x = x.split(", ")
    return (int(x[0]), x[1])
```

then use:

```
content = [my_process(x.strip('\n')) for x in file]
```

Answer (score -2):

use eval to convert str to python tuple, like this:

```
eval("(1, ' ')")
```

out:

```
(1, ' ')
```

in you case:

```
content = [eval(x.strip('\n')) for x in file]
```

to make the code safety, recommend use `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
content = [ast.literal_eval(x.strip('\n')) for x in file]
```

Comment: I would caution against doing `eval` on the contents of files and would recommend anyone dropping in here from the internet of the future takes a very serious look at whether or not they want to blindly execute whatever may be represented as code in a file.

Comment: @erewok sorry can you explain why it's dangerous ?

Comment: the file could contain virus code, and `eval` will then execute it...

Comment: `eval` takes a string and evaluates it is as code. Your program is processing data from a file. If there is malicious code in the file, you would be would running it by running `eval` on it.